# DML "10 chunks exception" and weird pattern

Tags: apex, dml

I am aware of `System.TypeException: Cannot have more than 10 chunks in a single operation` exception and it seems to be a known bug. I am also aware, that there are [some other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194740/system-typeexception-cannot-have-more-than-10-chunks-in-a-single-operation) one can encounter this exception.

However, after a while of playing with the limits, I found a pattern that shows how many records of some type one can insert in mixed-type DML. It seems to be:

```
maxRec = 2000 - (200 * T)
where
T - number of types in SObject[]
maxRec - max number of records of single type in sorted (by type) SObject[]
```

So, let's say we want to insert:

- 1400 Accounts
- 1 Contact
- 1 Bar__c
- 1 Foo__c

`insert myListOfSobjects;`

And that's perfectly fine. Now, if we would try to do the same, but instead of 1400 Accounts, we would try to insert 1401 of them, we should get our 10 chunks exception. Similarly, the following would work:

- 1800 Accounts
- 1 Foo__c

And it works as long as we'll try to insert 1800 Accounts. But wait, there's more.

If you try to add 1400 Accounts, 1 Contact, 1 Foo and 1 Bar, you could think - why couldn't I just add some more Foos? Here's your Collection:

- 1400 Accounts
- 1 Contact
- 1 Bar__c
- 201 Foo__c

Wrong (notice that we are far from 2000)! It seems that you cannot exceed the number of 200 within any type when one of your types reached the limit of `maxRec = 2000 - (200 * T)` ! So, to be more precise, what I found is:

```
maxRec = 2000 - (200 * T)
AND
maxRecForOthersTypes = 200
where

T - number of types in SObject[]
maxRec - max number of records of single type in sorted (by type) SObject[]
maxRecForOthers - records of type other then maxRec, if there is any. Limit for each type.
```

Now, the obvious, base question - why? I think it's hard to explain, as it's simply a bug, but seems to be a really deterministic one. Perhaps knowing the pattern, someone would have a better clue.

Comment: How are you inserting these records? What's the context? Depending on your code, a for loop may be the context that's limiting you to 200 "other" records. There are also other limits to take into consideration such as a max total of 10,000 DML records in a single execution context.

Comment: I believe, that "10 chunks..." limit may be hit irrespective of the context, but of course I'd mention if there were some special conditions. It's just a plain insert on List<Sobject> and the size is much less than 10000.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do a DML operation Salesforce breaks down the records into chunks of 200.  So if you insert or update say 2000 Accounts Salesforce actually does 10 chunks of 200.

Now when you try to do a mixed-type DML operation Salesforce first breaks apart each object and then splits them into chunks of 200 rounding up.  So in your first example

- 1400 Accounts = 7 chunks of 200
- 1 Contact = 1 chunk of 1
- 1 Bar__c = 1 chunk of 1
- 1 Foo__c = 1 chunk of 1

Which totals 10, so no problem.  No lets look at your last example

- 1400 Accounts = 7 chunks of 200
- 1 Contact = 1 chunk of 1
- 1 Bar__c = 1  chunk of 1
- 201 Foo__c = 2 total chunks. 1 chunk of 200 and 1 chunk of 1.

Here we have a total of 11 chunks which breaks the limit, even though we have less than 2000 records total.

---

**UDPATE:**

Per @Mossi and further testing the chunking only applies when the `List<sObject>` contains mixed types (ie Contact(s) and Account(s)).

If you use a `List<sObject>` with that only contains 1 type (ie only Contacts, or only Accounts) then it doesn't chunk and you can insert more that 2,000 records.

Comment: So are you saying that there is a limit of maximum 2000 records per DML call assuming they're all of the same type?

Comment: @Mossi  Yes, though I didn't explicitly state that as part of my answer, that is the conclusion I have come to.  If you have evidence that this is wrong I'd love to see it.

Comment: Just try inserting 4000 Contacts in Apex. It goes through fine. Here are 2 revealing examples: 1800 Contacts + 1 Account works, but with 1801 Contacts it fails. So your theory seems to hold only if the list contains mixed types.

Comment: @Mossi  I updated my answer to include your test results.  Thank you for the extra info.